# 8bit panels and hdr

Tags: displays

I'm looking into buying an Asus pg65uq when it's available, but I noticed something strange - it claims to support HDR10 while at the same time only supporting 8bit color. Doesn't those two contradict each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An 8-bit display can use [FRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate_control) to expand its perceived color range. It essentially dithers a pixel between two colors in time rather than with neighboring pixels.

Many monitors do this, in fact a lot of displays that support "16.7 Million Colors" (24-bit Color) are actually 6-bit panels using FRC.

If you are trying to decide between monitors, I wouldn't let this detail become a deciding factor. You are very likely looking at a monitor right now that uses FRC and you may not have noticed. It would be hard for most people to notice the quality improvement of a true 10-bit panel *without* FRC vs 8-bit with FRC.

Comment: Doesn't that mean the display cannot be advertised as supporting HDR10? It's even hdr 1000 certified when the standard requires 10bit depth.

Comment: @krojew, If I understand the `HDR10` spec correctly, it is only a standard for the transport of HDR content to a display. The display itself can support the signal, but then show it on a panel that has lower dynamic range than the signal. In this case an 8-bit panel + FRC is sufficient to present the HDR10 content with a dynamic range that is close enough to a true 10-bit panel.

Comment: You might be right. If I understand https://displayhdr.org/performance-criteria-cts1-1/ correctly, frc is permitted.

Comment: @krojew, It is good that this display goes as far as getting the DisplayHDR 1000 certification. *That* is the label you need to look for to ensure it actually has a decent color space and dynamic range. A display that just says "HDR10" could get away with anything as long as it supports the input signal.